# CSS layout div comes below and round table row

Tags: html, css

Need help with css.
My issues are:

1. Layout of the cards comes under each other
2. tr/td no options to round it

I'm tying to achieve a similar look to this:

[image]

I'm using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) to do this. My over all page layout that i am trying to go for:
[image]

This is what I have so far.

```
<div class="col m6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content"><span class="badge"><i class="material-icons dp48">search</i></span>
        <span class="card-title">My List
       <span class="new badge red" data-badge-caption="">4</span>
        </span>  
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table striped table-hover table-curved" ng-controller="Hello">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><b>12345</b></td>
                <td>Random Text @</td>
                <td><b>300121</b></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><b>12345678</b></td>
                <td>Random Text @</td>
                <td><b>300121</b></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col m6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">My List
       <span class="new badge red" data-badge-caption="">4</span>
        </span>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table striped table-hover table-curved" ng-controller="Hello">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><b>12345</b></td>
                <td>Random Text @</td>
                <td><b>300121</b></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><b>123</b></td>
                <td>Random Text @</td>
                <td><b>300121</b></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/tx3qpzsa/6

**UPDATE**

This is how it is currently:
[image]

---

But I want to do something like this:
[image]

Comment: your js fiddle seems appropriate? Can you better describe what issue(s) you are facing?

Comment: @BrandtSolovij In my layout pic, "My list" should be on the left hand side. and the rest right hand side. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: updated jsfiddle

Comment: Your rounded-corner issue can be solved with `border-collapse`, `border-spacing`, `:first-child` and `:last-child`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3427ej3p/). For everything else, there is [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

Comment: Updated question. need advice for1st problem

Comment: @shank, please take a look at my updated answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150183/3589528) for solution for your 1st problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below lines in [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/):

```
table.striped > tbody > tr > td {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

are very specific so if you set `table.striped td` (or similar) the above lines will overwrite your rules and remove your `border-radius`. You need to be more specific (or use `!important` statement - *not recommende*d).

You can for example use selector with the same specificity but adding your CSS after materializecss import:

```
table.striped > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

table.striped > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

*Above selectors are even more specific due to pseudo-selectors use.*

This should work well. Note that you need to set `border-radius` on `td` as it wouldn't work on `tr` element. That what `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-selectors are used for. I set right top and bottom border radius on first `td` and left top and bottom on last.

**Rounded corners demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/norin89/tx3qpzsa/7/

P.S. There's "External Resource" option on JSFiddle so you don't need to past whole file to CSS pane as you can import whole framework CSS :)

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want your tables to be composed like on the picture take a look at Materilize CSS Grid - http://materializecss.com/grid.html which id pretty similar to [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Columns (`.col`) should be direct children of element with class `.row` not a `.container` as in your code. I don't see anything about nesting `.row`s in the documentation but it seems to work well.

**Grid demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/norin89/tx3qpzsa/10/

Note that I used `<div class="col s12 m6">` so each column will be full width on narrow screens (one under another) and will change to 50% of width (`.m6`) on medium screens (due to [documentation](http://materializecss.com/grid.html#grid-responsive) wider than `600px`).

Comment: Thank you, got it now :)